# ruby if logged in use. loggedin.rhtml else use notloggedin.rhtml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

im having to use ruby instead of php, need to tell ruby if logged in use use loggedin.rhtml if not use notloggedin.rhtml. but the files only include part of the page a menu, so its like the php include function but with an if statement

Comment: Regardless of the login problem, how would Ruby "use PHP" to begin with? Why do you need to mix those two?

Comment: thought so, if i was calling it through ruby and just continue to use ruby and drop php is it possible to write that command in ruby?

Comment: Is it possible to write *if logged in, do A, else do B* in Ruby? I would surely hope so.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby can execute shell scripts and PHP is no exception.

```
if logged_in?
  output = `this.php`
else
  output = `that.php`
end
```

This will execute either `this.php` or `that.php` and store the scripts output in `output`, assuming the scripts have [*execute* permission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) and a proper [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
   echo "hello world";
?>
```

Note that this is like [using PHP from the command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), the scripts don't have access to any object in your Rails environment, i.e., you cannot use variables like [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) or [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). If you need any data in your script you have to pass it as an argument explicitly.

Comment: ok lets stick to ruby... i have a page and a basic menu div on the left which i have placed in a new notlogged.rhtml. and created a second menu loggedin.rhtml for when the user is logged in. so the page will load the relevent (template page) if logged in or not